# printf symbols with multiple space characters?

Tags: c, getchar

I have the following code to replace tab occurrences in stdin to four spaces. 
When I have stdin, separated by two spaces, e.g. "tab tab", the final printf prints the correct string "tab tab", however when my input is tab separated "tab	tab", and then four space characters are added instead, the final printf prints only "tab" string and nothing more. Any advice appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
#define TAB 4

void read_stdin(char s[], int len);

int main(){
    char str[MAX];
    read_stdin(str, MAX);
    return 0;
};

void read_stdin(char s[], int len){
    int i, ii;
    int c;
    for (i = 0; i < len && (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++){
        printf("c = %d, i = %d\n", c, i);

        if (c == '\t'){
            for (ii = 0; ii < TAB; ii++){
                printf("space ");
                s[i] = ' ';
                i++;
                printf("i = %d\n", i);
            };
        } else {
            s[i] = c;
        };
    };

    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("last i = %d\n", i);
    printf("string completed: %s\n", s);
};
```

in console, tabs separated by space character

```
tab tab
c = 116, i = 0
c = 97, i = 1
c = 98, i = 2
c = 32, i = 3
c = 116, i = 4
c = 97, i = 5
c = 98, i = 6
c = 10, i = 7
last i = 8
string completed: tab tab
```

and tabs separated by tab character

```
tab tab
c = 116, i = 0
c = 97, i = 1
c = 98, i = 2
c = 9, i = 3
space i = 4
space i = 5
space i = 6
space i = 7
c = 116, i = 8
c = 97, i = 9
c = 98, i = 10
c = 10, i = 11
last i = 12
string completed: tab
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please choose either C *or* C++ as tag, depending on which language you intend to write and compile against. These two are different languages. Your code seems valid for both, but is written as if it was C.

Comment: Note that the `};` after the loops and `else` clauses marks an empty statement after the loop.  You didn't (and cannot) put a semicolon after the braces surrounding the body of an `if` statement and then use `else` — that's a syntax error.  Those empty statements are nominally harmless, but they also show that you're not sure about the syntax of C.  The `};` at the end of the function has an empty declaration after the function.  That isn't so harmless; you should definitely omit that.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You need `};` when completing an initializer or a structure or union definition (`struct Tag { … };`) or an enum definition (`enum { V0, V1, … };`).  If you think of a compound literal as a cast and an initializer, that remains true; if you think of it otherwise, you need the semicolon.  In all these exception case, you sometimes don't need `};` — e.g. `typedef struct Tag { … } Tag;` or `struct Tag { … } tag;` (the latter declares a variable `tag` as well as the details of the type `struct Tag`).

Comment: `int i, ii;` defining variables with such names in the same scope is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` one time too many in the inner loop.

After the inner loop exits, `i` has the value 7 which would be the index of the next character to input.  But then the outer loop iterates, increasing `i` once more.  So you skip writing to index 7.  When you later try to print `s`, it reads this uninitialized character.  This character happens to have the value 0 in your particular case so the string appears to end there.

Decrement `i` at the end of the inner loop to put it back in the correct place.

```
        for (ii = 0; ii < TAB; ii++){
            printf("space ");
            s[i] = ' ';
            i++;
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
        };
        i--;
```

Comment: Another solution is to take `i++` out of the `for()` header, and assign to `s[i++]` in both places.

Comment: Not sure which I'd consider "cleaner".